# How to create array with same name from its function input parameter

Tags: java, arrays, string, parameters

How can I fix this:

```
class Name {

public void createArray(String name)
{
 String name=new String[200];//we know, we can't do this- duplicate local variable,need a fix here.
}
  }
```

I want to create array of strings with name of array as input parameter = name, 
Example:

1) for function call createArray(domain1) -> I need essentially this to happen-> String domain1=new String[200];

2)for function call createArray(domain22)-> I need function to create String domain22=new String[200];
Hope this edit helps.
NOTE: There is a possibility that same name is passed byfunction twice/thrice. like createArray(domain1);, at that point of time I want to ignore the creation of array.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  You want to create a new `String`?  Or an array of `String`s?  And you want to initialise them with what?  Why do you want two local variables with the same name?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Why can't you have the array as class member instead of local variable? Some thing like : ArrayList dynArray = new ArrayList(); ... ... createArray(String name) { dynArray.add(name); } ...

Comment: What you ask for in your question is not directly possible in Java. Variable names exist only at compile time, not at runtime.  The answer below from @MeBigFatGuy is the closest you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your new String[200] objects in a Map keyed by the name

```
Map<String, String[]> myarrays = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

myarrays.put("name", createArray("name"));
myarrays.put("test", createAray("test"));
```

then when you want one of them do

```
String[] data = myarrays.get("test");
```

Comment: This is the closest that you wanted. Use myarrays in your own method if the above looks difficult:
createArray(String name) { myarrays.put(name, new String[200]);} where myarrays remains as class level member, then you can iterate this map to find out "variable name" that you wanted, and array of string associated with those pseudo variable names.